# XDocument descendants is throwing a null reference

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I've got an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings updated="3/21/2017 15:48">
  <Setting name="ToolTipVariables">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Title&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Date&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Description&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Location&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Id&lt;/string&gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfString&gt;</Setting>
  <Setting name="ToolTipVariables">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Title&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Date&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Description&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Location&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Id&lt;/string&gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfString&gt;</Setting>
  <Setting name="ToolTipVariables">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Title&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Date&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Description&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Location&lt;/string&gt;
  &lt;string&gt;Id&lt;/string&gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfString&gt;</Setting>
  <Setting name="ShowUpdateWindow">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;boolean&gt;true&lt;/boolean&gt;</Setting>
</Settings>
```

And I'm trying to grab the first "ToolTipVariables" element like this:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(settingsPath); //settingsPath is where the XML Document is located
XElement element = document.Descendants("Settings").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "ToolTipVariables").FirstOrDefault();
```

but it keeps throwing a null reference exception when trying to get the FirstOrDefault. Maybe I'm making a simple mistake somewhere, but I can't find it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Clearly `x.Attribute("name")` must be null in some cases, so you want `Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "ToolTipVariables")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting all elements called `Settings` (where that is actually the root node.) The code `document.Descendants("Settings")` will give you all descendants of the document where the element name is `Settings`. I think what you really want is all `Setting` elements. This will work:

```
XElement element = document.Descendants("Setting")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "ToolTipVariables")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ah - there's the stupid mistake ;) . I misunderstood "Descendants" to mean "Descendants OF this" not "Descendants NAMED this". Thank you!